# Mysql left join on self or similar

Tags: mysql, left-join, self

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(spend.price) AS total, WEEKDAY(spend.date) AS weekday
FROM spend
WHERE spend.date BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-07'
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(spend.date) ;
```

Right now the query gives me only the days in which the user had some payments.

```
total weekday
60    2
10    3
3     5
3     6
```

But instead I want to give me 0 (zeros) for every day without payments.

```
total weekday
0     1
60    2
10    3
0     4
3     5
3     6
0     7
```

Table schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d1ec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(spend.price) AS total, day AS weekday
FROM (SELECT price, WEEKDAY(date) as day FROM spend WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-07'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,5
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,6
) spend
GROUP BY day ;
```

And here is the shortened one:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ( `price` int, `day` int );
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6);
SELECT SUM(spend.price) AS total, day AS weekday
FROM (SELECT price, WEEKDAY(date) as day FROM spend WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-07'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tmp
) spend
GROUP BY day ;
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c323/3/0

Comment: Drop date from your sub-query.  Otherwise this will throw an error.

Comment: @Tom I'm not selecting date in my sub query, but I do have to use it to check the range

Comment: Is there any shorter syntax to this problem? Because I'll have similar queries for grouping by months, years.

Comment: @simo I've found a shorter syntax, have a look

Comment: I think I got it to work for months too - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbf21/6. Can you put back the first syntax too, just for reference because I'm using it right now. And I'll mark your answer, thanks for the effort.